# Erro ao importar xls para o postgres

Tags: php, postgresql

Estou tentando importar um arquivo Xls para o banco de dados PostGresSql, porém 
quando executo o submit na própria pagina, ocorre o erro abaixo:

**Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\projetos... line 59**

Abaixo, segue o código:

```html
<div class="container-fluid"> 
 <fieldset class="bottom">
  <legend>Importação em Excel</legend> 
   <form action="#" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <fieldset>
   <div class="form-group">
    <input type='file' name='sel_file' size='20'>
   </div>
  </fieldset>
 <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Importar' class="btn btn-success">
</form>

<?php
 
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){ 

 if(!@($conexao=pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=teste user=postgres password=****"))) {
  print "Não foi possível estabelecer uma conexão com o banco de dados.";
 } else {
    print "Conexão OK!"; 
 }

     $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
     $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);

     if(strtolower($chk_ext[1]) == "xls"){
    
         $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
         $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
   
         while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    
           $sql = "INSERT into items(nome,email) values('$data[0]','$data[1]')";
      $result = pg_query($conexao, $sql);
         }
   
         fclose($handle);
         echo "Arquivo Importado com sucesso";
     }else{
         echo "Arquivo inválido";
     } 
 
}

?>
```

**A estrutura da tabela esta bem simples :**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**E o Arquivo Xls** :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já agradeço pela atenção.

Comment: Variáveis `Array` devem estar concatenadas no SQL.: Ex.: `('".$data[0]."','".$data[1]."')`

Comment: mesmo assim ocorre o erro:
Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\projetos\urm\... line 59 
Linha 59 ->  $sql = "INSERT into items(nome,email) values('".$data[0]."','".$data[1]."')";

Comment: E os dados, vem corretamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido !

```
if ($getLinha == ''){
    $getLinhaValor = 6;
}else {
    $getLinhaValor = $getLinha ;
}

//obten a linha do arquivo conforme a escolha do usuario
if ($linha_count > $getLinhaValor ){
   ..... code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Consegui inserindo o codigo abaixo:**

```html
 $file   = $_FILES ['sel_file' ]['tmp_name'] ; 
   $row = 1;
  if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    //$num = count($data);
    $row++;

    $veiculo = $data[0]; 
    $rd =$data[1];

    $sql = "INSERT into items(veiculo,rd) values('".$veiculo."','".$rd."')";
    $rs = pg_query($conexao, $sql);
   }
   
   if ($rs){ 
    echo   "Arquivo importado com sucesso !" ; 
    fclose($handle);
   }else{ 
    echo   "Erro ao carregar o arquivo" ; 
   } 
  }
```

**Portanto, gostaria de obter apenas as linhas começando da linha 6, ignorando o cabeçaho conforme abaixo:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]